# Add grouped by dataframe into multiple files?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a piece of code that I need to push into multiple HTML files and create a PDF withe them, I do not have any struggle with the PDF part of this, however I have an issue when creating the HTML files and pushing the data into the files. This is my code:

```
new_dataframe = dict(tuple(df.groupby(['Course'])))
for new_df in new_dataframe.values():
    print(new_df)
    new_index = new_df.index[-1]
    html_df = new_df.iloc[:new_index]
for i in range(len(unique_courses) - 1):
    if unique_courses[i] != unique_courses[i + 1]:
        file = open('example %s.html' % i, 'w')
        file.write(new_df.to_html())
```

the `file.write(new_df.to_html())` is what I am struggling on, as it is only taking the last dataframe that has been grouped by, and is turning that into HTML and then pushing the same data to all 4 files it has created instead of reading all 4 dataframes that I have and writing them to each file.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment on the `dict(tuple(...))` part, that was nonsense. Anyway, with the current indentation, the first loop will finish, `new_df` will keep the last value and that's all you ever pass to the second loop. What is `unique_courses`?

Comment: hello there, thanks for the response, sorry I should've added it in my description, "Unique courses" is the unique values of the dataframe column "Courses" so basically in my code "if unique_courses[i] != unique_courses[i + 1]:" for every value inside the list, if the previous value is not the same as the next, open the new file and write the html data to it

Comment: You can edit your question and add it there. That being said, how can the current value be equal to the next one if it's unique values?

Comment: sorry I'm new to asking questions, you're totally right, I'm not sure why I actually put that there now I think about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, something like this should work.

```py
new_dataframe = dict(tuple(df.groupby(['Course'])))
for course, new_df in new_dataframe.items():
    with open(f'example_{course}.html', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(new_df.to_html())
```

Comment: You're an absolute gent, that worked perfectly. Thank you for your help I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Glad to help! If this solves your problem, you can accept the answer by clicking the check sign next to it. If it doesn't quite work yet, feel free to comment. :)